# Testing WCF web service locally project after client was using this web service in remote address

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

I have a `.NET` project that uses an `WCF` web service. I got from the client the endpoint address and contract and I started working with this service - all good.
Now I got from this project with the `WCF` web service so I could make some changes.

After I did my changes  I can't figure how can I test it work with THAT new web service and not the remote one. If I understand it right so after that I can host it one the same domain
that the original service is working on.

In the WCF project I see in `web.config` (no `app.config` file) the next code:

```
 <services>
      <service name="MyAnService.AnService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="anBinding"
          name="Local" contract="AnServiceContracts.Interfaces.IAnService" />
        <host>
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:00:15" />
        </host>
      </service>
```

So what I asking is how do I take this `WCF` project and connect to it (want to debug it) from my other `.NET` project before I host it on other server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to add a reference to the web service.  In the solution explorer of Visual Studio, right click on the project name, select add, select reference.  Then choose your web service.